# Create NSArray from plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Im trying to create an NSArray from a plist but for some reason the array never get initialised.

Heres the code -

```
NSString * path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"defaultWorkouts2" ofType:@"plist"];

    NSLog(@" ------ %@", path);

    NSArray * defaultWorkouts = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

    NSLog(@" ------ %@", defaultWorkouts);
```

Heres the console output -

`2011-04-24 16:17:26.732 IntervalTimer[9778:207]  ------ file://localhost/Users/darrenfindlay/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/4.3/Applications/8FAC4993-D1BA-460F-9A56-8A6984CB8AB6/IntervalTimer.app/defaultWorkouts.plist
2011-04-24 16:17:26.733 IntervalTimer[9778:207]  ------ (null))`

Here is the plist file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Boxing</key>
    <array>
        <integer>8</integer>
        <string>Sparring</string>
        <array>
            <integer>150</integer>
            <integer>60</integer>
            <integer>150</integer>
            <integer>60</integer>
            <integer>150</integer>
            <integer>60</integer>
            <integer>150</integer>
            <integer>60</integer>
            <integer>150</integer>
            <integer>60</integer>
            <integer>150</integer>
            <integer>60</integer>
            <integer>150</integer>
            <integer>60</integer>
            <integer>150</integer>
        </array>
        <array>
            <string>Round 1</string>
            <string>Rest, Round 2 next</string>
            <string>Round 2</string>
            <string>Rest, Round 3 next</string>
            <string>Round 3</string>
            <string>Rest, Round 4 next</string>
            <string>Round 4</string>
            <string>Rest, Round 5 next</string>
            <string>Round 5</string>
            <string>Rest, Round 6 next</string>
            <string>Round 6</string>
            <string>Rest, Round 7 next</string>
            <string>Round 7</string>
            <string>Rest, Round 8 next</string>
            <string>Round 8</string>
        </array>
    </array>
    <key>Boxing - 2</key>
    <array>
        <integer>8</integer>
        <string>Sparring</string>
        <array>
            <integer>150</integer>
            <integer>60</integer>
            <integer>150</integer>
            <integer>60</integer>
            <integer>150</integer>
            <integer>60</integer>
            <integer>150</integer>
            <integer>60</integer>
            <integer>150</integer>
            <integer>60</integer>
            <integer>150</integer>
            <integer>60</integer>
            <integer>150</integer>
            <integer>60</integer>
            <integer>150</integer>
        </array>
        <array>
            <string>Round 1</string>
            <string>Rest, Round 2 next</string>
            <string>Round 2</string>
            <string>Rest, Round 3 next</string>
            <string>Round 3</string>
            <string>Rest, Round 4 next</string>
            <string>Round 4</string>
            <string>Rest, Round 5 next</string>
            <string>Round 5</string>
            <string>Rest, Round 6 next</string>
            <string>Round 6</string>
            <string>Rest, Round 7 next</string>
            <string>Round 7</string>
            <string>Rest, Round 8 next</string>
            <string>Round 8</string>
        </array>
    </array>
    <key>Boxing - 3</key>
    <array>
        <integer>8</integer>
        <string>Sparring</string>
        <array>
            <integer>150</integer>
            <integer>60</integer>
            <integer>150</integer>
            <integer>60</integer>
            <integer>150</integer>
            <integer>60</integer>
            <integer>150</integer>
            <integer>60</integer>
            <integer>150</integer>
            <integer>60</integer>
            <integer>150</integer>
            <integer>60</integer>
            <integer>150</integer>
            <integer>60</integer>
            <integer>150</integer>
        </array>
        <array>
            <string>Round 1</string>
            <string>Rest, Round 2 next</string>
            <string>Round 2</string>
            <string>Rest, Round 3 next</string>
            <string>Round 3</string>
            <string>Rest, Round 4 next</string>
            <string>Round 4</string>
            <string>Rest, Round 5 next</string>
            <string>Round 5</string>
            <string>Rest, Round 6 next</string>
            <string>Round 6</string>
            <string>Rest, Round 7 next</string>
            <string>Round 7</string>
            <string>Rest, Round 8 next</string>
            <string>Round 8</string>
        </array>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Thanks in advance for any help, this is driving me crazy.

Comment: You should use `-[NSBundle URLForResource:ofType:]` and `-[NSArray initWithContentsOfURL:]` as Apple recommends that.

Comment: show your plist file. It looks like this file does not hold a valid array representation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tryed that but still no luck, I got the exact same output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at your plist file, it's holding a `NSDictionary` not a `NSArray`. You should change your implementation to:

```
NSDictionary * defaultWorkouts = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```